# EntitlementServiceStub - get multiple decisions

Tags: xacml3, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to use a PEP client to get the XACML authorization decisions
I am following the steps given in [this article](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/06/14/pep-client-for-wso2is-pdp/)

I can see that they use `entitlementServiceStub.getDecisionByAttributes` to get the decission.

I want to get decisions of the children for a root resource in a hierarchy (multiple decisions)

**Which API/method I need to use?**
I couldn't find any documentation or source for `EntitlementServiceStub`.

Regards,
Albie Morken

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getDecision` operation for this. Please refer [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/12/09/multiple-decision-profile-hierarchical-resources/) for a detailed example.